# distance matrix api gives incorrect data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance, google-distancematrix-api

When I measure 2 different locations with Google distance matrix, it shares it as 181km. When I measure it with a ruler on Yandex Map, it says 133.6km. In the 3D tests on calculater.net, it says 133.6km. Can someone please explain to me what this means? Sample results =>

https://www.calculator.net/distance-calculator.html?la1=41.0161299&lo1=28.8950763&la2=41.624271&lo2=27.517888&lad1=38&lam1=53&las1=51.36&lau1=n&lod1=77&lom1=2&los1=11.76&lou1=w&lad2=39&lam2=56&las2=58.56&lau2=n&lod2=75&lom2=9&los2=1.08&lou2=w&type=3&ctype=dec&x=Calculate#latlog =>result 133.6km

curl --location 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=41.0161299%2C28.8950763&destinations=41.624271%2C27.517888&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY' =>result 181km

[https://yandex.ru/maps/106171/vize/?ll=27.876209%2C41.514851&mode=routes&rl=28.895412%2C41.015080~-1.377644%2C0.609124&routes%5BactiveComparisonMode%5D=auto&routes%5BignoreTravelModes%5D=bicycle%2Cscooter&rtext=41.624271%2C27.517887~41.016130%2C28.895076&rtt=comparison&ruri=~&z=10.09](https://yandex.ru/maps/106171/vize/?ll=27.876209%2C41.514851&mode=routes&rl=28.895412%2C41.015080%7E-1.377644%2C0.609124&routes%5BactiveComparisonMode%5D=auto&routes%5BignoreTravelModes%5D=bicycle%2Cscooter&rtext=41.624271%2C27.517887%7E41.016130%2C28.895076&rtt=comparison&ruri=%7E&z=10.09) =>result 134km

I was expecting the google distance matrix api to give the correct result, but I was wrong.

Comment: How do you "measure it with a ruler on Yandex Map"? Using the DirectionsService (which shows the route): Walking distance (shortest route, probably not fastest for driving, or necessarily drivable) 160 km, Driving distance (about 2 hrs 8 min) 181 km. The distance I expect for the DistanceMatrix is that returned by the DirectionsService.

Comment: so google distance. How will I measure direct distance with matrix?

Comment: The distance matrix returns a driving distance (or other travel mode if configured), if you want "straight line distance, that is different, doesn't require a service,.